# CodeIgniter : View Table Data from Double Relation Table

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-4, phpmyadmin, codeigniter-3

I use CodeIgniter for this project. On the "v_pembayaran_admin" page, I have a table called "pembayaran" that has to show a column called "nama_user". The "nama_user" column takes data from "pendaftar" table but through "user" table. So, the column "nama_user" from "pendaftar" table will only appear in "pembayaran" table if it already exists in "user" table. I already try some ways, but I can't find the final result that I want and it appears an error. Please help me to resolve it quickly.
[image: The table join's picture]. [image: This is the error that appears]. the chain is "pembayaran"->"user"->"pendaftar.

Pembayaran's controller :

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('pembayaran_m');
    $data['data_pembayaran']=$this->pembayaran_m->get_pembayaran();
    $this->load->model('user_m');
    $data['data_user']=$this->user_m->get_user();
    $this->load->model('pertemuan_m');
    $data['data_pertemuan']=$this->pertemuan_m->get_pertemuan();
    $this->load->view('v_pembayaran_admin', $data);
    $this->load->view('template');
}
```

Pembayaran's model :

```
public function get_pembayaran()
{
    $data_pembayaran = $this->db
        ->join('user','user.id_user=pembayaran.id_user')
        ->join('pertemuan','pertemuan.id_pertemuan=pembayaran.id_pertemuan')
        ->get('pembayaran')
        ->result_array();
    return $data_pembayaran;
}

public function masuk_db()
{
    $data_pembayaran=array(
        'tgl_bayar'=>$this->input->post('tgl_bayar'),
        'id_user'=>$this->input->post('id_user'),
        'id_pertemuan'=>$this->input->post('id_pertemuan'),
        'uang_kursus'=>$this->input->post('uang_kursus'),
        'uang_daftar'=>$this->input->post('uang_daftar'),
        'total'=>$this->input->post('total'),
        'via'=>$this->input->post('via'),
        'ket'=>$this->input->post('ket')
    );
    $sql_masuk=$this->db->insert('pembayaran', $data_pembayaran);
    return $sql_masuk;
}
```

Pembayaran's View :

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
            <tr>
              <th>NO</th>
              <th>TANGGAL BAYAR</th>
              <th>NAMA SISWA</th>
              <th>TOTAL PERTEMUAN</th>
              <th>UANG KURSUS</th>
              <th>UANG PENDAFTARAN</th>
              <th>TOTAL TAGIHAN</th>
              <th>VIA</th>
              <th>KETERANGAN</th>
              <th>AKSI</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
              $no=0;
              foreach ($data_pembayaran as $byr) {
                $no++;
                echo '<tr>
                  <td>'.$no.'</td>
                  <td>'.$byr['tgl_bayar'].'</td>
                  <td>'.$byr['nama_user'].'</td>
                  <td>'.$byr['pertemuan'].'</td>
                  <td>Rp '.$byr['uang_kursus'].'</td>
                  <td>Rp '.$byr['uang_daftar'].'</td>
                  <td>Rp '.$byr['total'].'</td>
                  <td>'.$byr['via'].'</td>
                  <td>'.$byr['ket'].'</td>
                  <td><a href="#update_pembayaran" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal"
                  onclick="tm_detail('.$byr['id_pembayaran'].')">Update</a>
                  <a href="'.base_url('index.php/Pembayaran/hapus_pembayaran/'.$byr['id_pembayaran']).'"
                  class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm(\'Yakin Hapus?\')">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>';
              }
            ?>
          </table>
```

Please help me..

Comment: you didnt shared `pertemuan_m` model need to check this method `get_pertemuan`

Answer (score 0):

```
  please change your ' get_pembayaran ' model code 


  public function get_pembayaran()
   {
       $data_pembayaran = $this->db
          ->join('user','user.id_user=pembayaran.id_user')
          ->join('pertemuan','pertemuan.id_pertemuan=pembayaran.id_pertemuan')
          ->join('pendaftar','pendaftar.id_pendaftar=pembayaran.id_pertemuan')
          ->get('pembayaran')
          ->result_array();
       return $data_pembayaran;
   }
```